# close fxml window by code, javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml

I need to close the current fxml window by code in the controller

> I know stage.close() or stage.hide() do this in fx

how to implement this in fxml? I tried

```
private void on_btnClose_clicked(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("currentWindow.fxml"));    
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        Stage stage = new Stage();            
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
}
```

but it doesn't work!

All help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 184, accepted):

1. give your close button an fx:id, if you haven't yet: `<Button fx:id="closeButton" onAction="#closeButtonAction">`
2. In your controller class:

   ```
   @FXML private javafx.scene.control.Button closeButton;

   @FXML
   private void closeButtonAction(){
       // get a handle to the stage
       Stage stage = (Stage) closeButton.getScene().getWindow();
       // do what you have to do
       stage.close();
   }
   ```

Comment: This approach did not work for me. I receive a `NullPointerException`

Comment: amazing Works  !  , just in case,  people remember check the name of your Button (this case closeButton)and the name of your onClick (this case closeButtonAction)

Comment: I get this error when I use this code.  Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.javafx.stage.EmbeddedWindow cannot be cast to javafx.stage.Stage

Comment: @ZinMinn if you want to close the app, just call Platform.exit(). Closing a stage is different than closing the app (you can have multiple stages).

Comment: This solution is perfect to close a secondary window. `closeButton` must be a button in the window to close and the method `closeButtonAction()` must be in the same class also.

Comment: @AustinD probably your Button in Controller is declared as private

Comment: He forgot the prameter ActionEvent event

Answer (score 25):

If you have a window which extends `javafx.application.Application;` you can use the following method.
(This will close the whole application, not just the window. I misinterpreted the OP, thanks to the commenters for pointing it out).

```
Platform.exit();
```

Example:

```
public class MainGUI extends Application {
.........

Button exitButton = new Button("Exit");
exitButton.setOnAction(new ExitButtonListener());
.........

public class ExitButtonListener implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

  @Override
  public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
    Platform.exit();
  }
}
```

**Edit for the beauty of Java 8:**

```
 public class MainGUI extends Application {
    .........

    Button exitButton = new Button("Exit");
    exitButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> Platform.exit());
 }
```

Comment: `Platform.exit()` will close all stages and shot down the entire application. This might not be desired.

Comment: The original poster was asking how to close a window (stage), not the application.

Answer (score 12):

I implemented this in the following way after receiving a `NullPointerException` from the accepted answer.

In my FXML:

```
<Button onMouseClicked="#onMouseClickedCancelBtn" text="Cancel">
```

In my `Controller` class:

```
@FXML public void onMouseClickedCancelBtn(InputEvent e) {
    final Node source = (Node) e.getSource();
    final Stage stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to overspread your controller with fxml linked methods you can do something like this:

You have to give it a "fx:id", like "closeButton" for example. Should look like this in your FXML file:

```
<Button fx:id="closeButton" layoutX="876.0" layoutY="74.0" mnemonicParsing="false" textAlignment="CENTER">
```

Then you can just code the button in your initialize method or wherever you want:

```
@FXML
Button closeButton

public initialize(){
    closeButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e){
            ((Stage) closeButton.getScene().getWindow()).close();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hide doesn't close the window, just put in visible mode.
The best solution was:

```
@FXML
private void exitButtonOnAction(ActionEvent event){
        ((Stage)(((Button)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow())).close();      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best way (or if it works), but you could try:

```
private void on_btnClose_clicked(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        Window window = getScene().getWindow();   

        if (window instanceof Stage){
            ((Stage) window).close();
        }
}
```

(Assuming your controller is a Node. Otherwise you have to get the node first (getScene() is a method of Node)

Answer (score 1):

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    public void handle(WindowEvent we) {                        
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        stage.close();
    }
});
```

It is equivalent to `hide`. So when you are going to open it next time, you just check if the `stage` object is exited or not. If it is exited, you just `show()` i.e. `(stage.show())` call. Otherwise, you have to start the stage.

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice solution which does not need an event to be triggered:

```
@FXML
private Button cancelButton;

close(new Event(cancelButton, stage, null));

@FXML
private void close(Event event) {
    ((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();                      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

finally, I found a solution

```
 Window window =   ((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow(); 
            if (window instanceof Stage){
                ((Stage) window).close();
            }
```