# how to blend JFXNodeList from the code

Tags: javafx, jfoenix

I am having a JFXNodeList

```
<JFXNodesList fx:id="algorithmList" layoutX="285.0" layoutY="215.0" prefHeight="1.0" prefWidth="10.0" />
```

How can I close (blend the JFXNodeList), from my controller java code, if a user click one button ?

Environment:
JavaFX , Java 8, jfoenix:8.0.3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037724/how-to-close-a-java-window-with-a-button-click-javafx-project

Comment: this is not a window, it is float button list from the jfoenix library

Comment: But it's the window you want to close, right???

Comment: I edited the question so must be more clear now

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To close (collapse) `JFXNodeList` you can use this method:

```
nodesList.animateList(false);
```

Complete example:

// src/toumi_jfoenix/`Controller.java:`

```java
package toumi_jfoenix;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXNodesList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    public JFXNodesList nodesList;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        JFXButton btnMenu = new JFXButton("Menu");
        JFXButton btnOption1 = new JFXButton("Option 1");
        JFXButton btnOption2 = new JFXButton("Option 2");

        JFXButton btnCollapse = new JFXButton("<<");
        btnCollapse.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Collapse menu"));
        btnCollapse.setOnAction(e->nodesList.animateList(false));

        nodesList.addAnimatedNode(btnMenu);
        nodesList.addAnimatedNode(btnOption1);
        nodesList.addAnimatedNode(btnOption2);
        nodesList.addAnimatedNode(btnCollapse);
    }
}
```

// src/toumi_jfoenix/`sample.fxml:`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXNodesList?>

<Pane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="toumi_jfoenix.Controller">

    <JFXNodesList fx:id="nodesList" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="10.0" rotate="-90" spacing="50"/>

</Pane>
```

// src/toumi_jfoenix/`Main.java:`

```java
package toumi_jfoenix;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 430, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```