# Why are Stage size and location not maintained after reopening?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-2

I want to keep the last location of a `Stage` on the screen when the user moves the `Stage` and closes it. In Swing, if I keep the same instance of a window, it will be displayed at the same location after moved, closed and reopened. Why is `Stage` always shown at same location in JavaFX?

Check my code sample below:

```
aboutStage = new Stage();
aboutStage.setTitle("About " + Constants.APP_TITLE);
aboutStage.setResizable(false);
aboutStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
aboutStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
aboutStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);

Parent page = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(
        AboutWindowController.class.getResource("about.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(page);
aboutStage.setScene(scene);



miAbout.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
        Stage about = mainClass.getAboutStage();
        about.show();
    }
});
```

Example of Swing code:

```
public class SwingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JButton b = new JButton("Show Dialog");
        final JDialog d = new JDialog(f);
        d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        d.setSize(300, 300);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                d.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(b);
        f.add(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

If you test this code, open the dialog and move it, then close and reopen it. You will see that the dialog is at the same state when it is reopened.

Answer (score 1):

In your SWING implementation, you are disposing the window which marks it undisplayable. When you make re-display the JDialog, Swing APIs create it with the same state at which it was disposed. Check out the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29)

In case of JavaFX, whether you hide the window with hide() method or close the window with close() method, the state of stage can not be reproduced(unless of course you program it manually ). Check out the [Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212366/javafx-2-0-closing-a-stage-window)
Unfortunately, this is how the APIs are created.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to understand the question completely. Could you please be a little more precise on how are you displaying the window in SAME location in swing.

As I understand, the only way a window would appear in same location after closing the window is when you use the default behavior of JFrame which is to hide the window (Not to exit).
Whereas in case of JavaFX Scene, you are loading a new resource which is like opening a new window from scratch.

Please also note that you can integrate Swing with JavaFX. Click [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/integrating-javafx-20-swing) to know more

Comment: On Swing I reuse the same JDialog instance. When I close it and open again, the state is exactly the same, i.e., it is at same location and has same size that when it was visible.