# JavaFX open new window

Tags: javafx-2

Looking at [this code](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/netbeans/javafx2.samples/FXML-LoginDemo/src/demo/Main.java) they show a way to display a new window after a login. When username and password are correct it opens new dialog. I want a button click to open new dialog, without checking for username and password.

Comment: It's important that you take the time to learn this kind of stuff.  I you are looking to use JavaFX in any way, I would suggest going through a few tutorials.  I would recommend [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm)

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 105, accepted):

If you just want a button to open up a new window, then something like this works:

```
btnOpenNewWindow.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Parent root;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("path/to/other/view.fxml"), resources);
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("My New Stage Title");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 450, 450));
            stage.show();
            // Hide this current window (if this is what you want)
            ((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to 'drop' the existing window instead of hiding it?

Comment: @will `close`ing and `hide`ing a window is the same thing.  ­[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10217157/686036) is good at explaining this concept.

Comment: I mean drop it as-in delete the instance.  I have a long running app (weeks) and I don't need any resources un-garbage collected to gather lint.

Comment: That's exactly it.  `hide`ing it or `close`ing it will remove it.  Just delete any reference to this window/stage (such you would do with any other java object).

Comment: I'm trying to hide window from menuitem `ActionEvent` but getting exception "menuitem cannot be casted to Node".
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.control.MenuItem cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Node`

Comment: Is there any reason for not declaring root just where you initialize it?

Comment: @Line In this example not really.  But assuming you want to do something else with `root` outside of the try block then it would be useful.

Answer (score 21):

I use the following method in my JavaFX applications.

```
newWindowButton.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("NewWindow.fxml"));
        /* 
         * if "fx:controller" is not set in fxml
         * fxmlLoader.setController(NewWindowController);
         */
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 600, 400);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("New Window");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to create new Window.", e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The code below worked for me I used part of the code above inside the button class.

```
public Button signupB;

public void handleButtonClick (){

    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("sceneNotAvailable.fxml"));
        /*
         * if "fx:controller" is not set in fxml
         * fxmlLoader.setController(NewWindowController);
         */
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 630, 400);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("New Window");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to create new Window.", e);
    }

}

}
```