# JavaFX can't set the text of Label or Text

Tags: java

I don't know why this is not working. I want to set the text of a Label or Text. ( it does not matter which if it works). The label stays the same. When I use Text the application just crashes...

```java
@FXML
    public Text txtMessage;
    @FXML
    public Text txtTitle;
    @FXML
    public Text txtResult;

    @FXML
    public Label lblResult;


    public void display(String title, String message) throws IOException {
        txtResult = new Text();
        lblResult = new Label();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        Parent root= FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Alertbox.fxml"));
        lblResult.setText("message");

        stage.setTitle(title);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }
```

It has 2 parameters. I tried adding @FXML, or removing @FXML but both does not work. I also tried to initialize the label and text.

```java
 txtResult = new Text();
 lblResult = new Label();
```

I debugged the code. message is a string and contains the right message.

Comment: You do not need to create new Text or Label, they are injected by the @FXML annotation and corresponding FXML file.

Comment: It still does not work if I remove the 'create new Text or Label'

Comment: What is in `Alertbox.fxml`? Also, is this class the controller for it? And, where do you set the text and what error message is the result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX new custom pop out window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37414441/javafx-new-custom-pop-out-window)

Comment: @tevemadar Yes that class is the controller for it. The class has a method called 'display'. The class does not have a constructor. Hmmm seems like I do not get errors. I just get warnings, but that are some other reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller should not be created when you call `FXMLLoader.load` as `load` will create the controller. You should also not use the static version of load. Your code should look somethink like:

```
public static ControllerClass display(String title, String message) throws IOException {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent root= loader.load(getClass().getResource("/Alertbox.fxml"));
    ControllerClass controller = loader.getController();    
    controller.lblResult.setText("message");
    stage.setTitle(title);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();
    return controller;
```

}

This is still probably not exactly right, but it should point you in the correct direction.

Note, ControllerClass is the class name of your controller.

Comment: Why are you returning controller? I want to go to a new screen, send a parameter to the new screen. that's it :P

Comment: I case you need to store a reference to it somewhere, just a habit not required.

Comment: Aah okay! I fixed it