# Opening a Separate JavaFX Window from a Separate Class

Tags: java, javafx

So I'm trying to open a second JavaFX window on a specific button click to perform a separate function. How should I proceed given the code below from my `MainGUI` and attempting to link a class titled NearLocationsGUI which would open when the button is clicked:

```
        Button nearMe = new Button();
        nearMe.setText("Find Locations Near Me");


        nearMe.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Locations Near Me Found!");
                NearestLocationsGUI.launch();
            }
        });
```

Not a duplicate of this post: [JavaFX open new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041760/javafx-open-new-window) because that was working with FXML, which I am not, and creating a new window in the same class, I have an in depth second class I need to open- almost like a second application.

Comment: Not a duplicate- that was utilizing FXML not a standard JavaFX class

Answer (score 2):

You just have create a new stage then say newStage.show();

Comment: What would I use as the argument for Show?

Comment: [`show()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#show--) has no arguments.